# Calling model functions in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, model

i am trying to work with CodeIgniter the same way as i work in RoR, and then use functions defined in the model in the views, and so on. Let me explain with some example:

My user controller

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Users extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function show($id) {
        $user = $this->user_model->get($id);
        $this->data['user'] = $user;
        $this->load_view('users/show');
    }

}
```

My user model

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User_model extends MY_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function who() {
        return ( $this->name ) ? $this->name : $this->email;
    }

}
```

And then i want to do this in my view

```
...
<main>
    <h3><?= $user->who() ?></h3>
</main>
...
```

How can i achieve this?

NOTE: If i echo

```
$user->email
```

it works fine...

Comment: If you want something RoR-ish, you might want to take a look at Laravel instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just missing the data passed into your view. There's also a typo on the $this->load->view().

```
$this->load->view('users/show', $this->data);
```

Also, are you using?

https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model

Comment: Thanks, i am using a MY_Controller class that have a load_view method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that CI does not work the same way as rails. Here:

`$user = $this->user_model->get($id);`

You are assigning an object that is created dynamically by the ActiveRecord implementation of CI when you call `get` on the object, hence, that object would not have the `who` method. This, however, would work:

`$this->user_model->who()`

Because at that scope, in the controller, `user_model` is just an instance of your `User_model` class which is where `who` is declared.

My advice would be to use a [custom helper](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html) for that kind of functionality. CI models don't work as Rails models